# Google Tag Manager Best Practices & Anti-Patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager, web-analytics

I work on a large site that uses GTM and have seen a couple instances recently where conflicts between site code & GTM tags/scripts have led to issues( malformed links, broken submit buttons etc).

I work on the developer side, not the web analytic side, & was wondering 1) What Best Practices should  you follow for minimizing potential conflicts & 2) What anti-patterns ( things to avoid) have you seen? 
GTM is clearly a powerful tool, but with great power comes great responsibility.  I want to make a few suggestions for what our internal GTM users can do to minimize problems in the future.

One Best Practice seems to be to take great care with the Custom HTML Tag.  What others are there?

Answer (score 0):

You've nailed the big one. The custom HTML tag is a very sharp two-edged sword. I usually tell clients that custom HTML tags require a JavaScript developer and that they should never cut-and-paste any code into the tag -- no matter what their silly third-party tracking vendor says.

I also let them know if I have to fix problems with custom HTML tags, that it will cost more than if they had asked for help in the first place.

Other than the custom HTML tag, there's little that can really mess up functionality of the page. However, there is plenty they can do to break analytics.

There are also custom JavaScript macros that can cause problems, but they're not as discoverable, so don't get abused as much as custom HTML tags.

I find that using consistent naming conventions for tags, rules, and macros really helps when it comes to maintenance and troubleshooting. I like to name things starting with the most general information and end with the most specific. For example "GA Event - Download PDF" and "Listener - Link Click" for tags, "Link Click - Download PDF" for rules. I like to use all lower-case for macros.